# How to get google static map with scale 2 and returns 2048x2048 pixels without Premium Plan

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

When I get google static map with scale is 2, I only get map size with maximum is 640px. How can I get google static map with scale is 2 and maximum image size up tp 1024 without upgrade account to Premium Plan???

Answer (score 3):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0,0&zoom=2&size=1024x1024&scale=2
```

This returns a map of size 1024x1024 with scale 2.

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Imagesizes) states that you can get 1280 x 1280 without Premium Plan.

Comment: This document said get 1280px but with scale 2 picture size will be 1280 / 2 = 640px

Comment: I agree the documentation is a bit confusing. But if you save the image to your machine, you'll see that the dimensions are in fact 1024x1024

Comment: Now i can save picture with 1024px but if use scale 2, google map size must only 640px. As my question, I need output pic is 2048px not 1024px. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're going to need the Premium Plan then

Comment: I think so too, Thanks Thomas